# C++，sqlite3. How to deal with BLOB field when it's used as a query condition?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I got a sqlit3 db and I can't modify it.
​I need to get a record with code '5000154130' and number '03719552' from table t_major.

From Navicat,I found the code and number's type are all **VARCHAR**.In Navicat the value of code and number are '5000154130' and '03719552',but after I exported the record,the value changed to be 'NTAwMDE1NDEzMAA=' and 'MDM3MTk1NTMA'.

The original insertion sql is `"INSERT INTO "main"."t_major" ("code","number",...) VALUES(X'5000154130',X'03719552',...);"`. This X should mean **BLOB**.

​All of the following sql cannot get the result.

> invalid sql

```
SELECT * FROM t_major WHERE code='5000154130' and number='03719552';
SELECT * FROM t_major WHERE code=hex('5000154130') and hex(number='03719552');
SELECT * FROM t_major WHERE code='5000154130' and number LIKE '03719552';
```

​Only this works.

```
SELECT * FROM t_major WHERE code LIKE '%5000154130%' and number LIKE '%03719552%';
```

​Any suggestion？

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html is **essential** reading for understanding how Sqlite works. Your question tells me you haven't read it.

> I found the code and number's type are all VARCHAR

Sqlite does not have a `VARCHAR` type; when that is used in a column definition, it's treated as having `TEXT` affinity because it has the string "CHAR" in it. But you're inserting `BLOB`s into the table. Sqlite will not convert a blob to any other type when storing it in a table, no matter the column's affinity.

In your first three `SELECT`s, you're then comparing the blob in the table (`X'5000154130'`) to a text value (`'5000154130'`) using `=`. This comparison is never going to be true:

From the documentation (Emphasis added):

> The results of a comparison depend on the storage classes of the operands, according to the following rules:
>
> - A value with storage class NULL is considered less than any other value (including another value with storage class NULL).
> - An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value. When an INTEGER or REAL is compared to another INTEGER or REAL, a numerical comparison is performed.
> - **A TEXT value is less than a BLOB value**. When two TEXT values are compared an appropriate collating sequence is used to determine the result.
> - When two BLOB values are compared, the result is determined using memcmp().

Your fourth one... shouldn't match anything either. It doesn't in my testing. Even if sqlite treats the blob as text in the case of `LIKE`, the values being compared don't match up (The blob `X'0102'` is the bytes `0x01 0x02`, the string `'0102'` is the bytes `0x30 0x31 0x30 0x32`)

---

Basically, if you want to treat these values as strings, don't insert them as blobs. If you can't control that, look up records by comparing them to the appropriate blobs, not strings.

---

Edit:

I don't know what you mean by *exported the record*, but `NTAwMDE1NDEzMAA=` is the Base64 encoding of the *string* `'5000154130'` (`UAAVQTA=` is the Base64 encoding of the *blob* `X'5000154130'`).

Comment: Export means export the data into an excel with Navicat,but I don't know why its value changed to be base64 encoding.After reading the aritcle you mentioned,I found that the type of column is not blob,the result of 'SELECT typeof(code) FROM t_major;' is **TEXT**.More confused about it,because the insertion sql what I get from Navicat is X'5000154130',accroding from sqlite3 manual,the type of column should be **BLOB** regardless of column affinity.Then I tried following sql,still not worked. \r\n"SELECT... WHERE ("fpdm"=X'3530303031383431333000');" ; "SELECT... WHERE ("fpdm"=X'5000154130');"